# Make a multi-column legend in Earth Engine Apps

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a map with many classes that I want to display in an Earth Engine App. I want to include a legend that lists map class color with a label. I can do this for a single column of classes, but there are so many classes that the legend extends beyond the bounds of the page. How can I create a multi-column legend?

Here is a minimal example of how I'm creating a single column legend.

```js
// Class color and label info.
var classInfo = [
  {name: 'Forest', color: 'green'},
  {name: 'Rock', color: 'grey'},
  {name: 'Water', color: 'blue'},
  {name: 'Grass', color: 'yellow'}
];

// Makes a legend entry: color and label side-by-side in a panel.
function legendEntry(info) {
  var color = ui.Panel({style: {
    width: '20px',
    height: '20px',
    backgroundColor: info.color,
    margin: '6px 0px 0px 0px'
  }});
  var label = ui.Label({
    value: info.name,
  });
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [color, label],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
    style: {
      stretch: 'horizontal',
      margin: '-6px 0px 0px 0px'
    }});
}

// Define a panel to hold all legend entries.
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 8px 0px 8px' 
  }
});

// Loop through the map classes, add each entry to the legend panel.
for (var i = 0; i < classInfo.length; i++) {
  legend.add(legendEntry(classInfo[i]));
}

// Show legend on the map.
Map.add(legend);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple columns you can follow your current workflow, except that you need to add a second dimension to the `classInfo` object to define columns and rows and also do a nested for loop to cycle through both dimensions.

Here is an approach based on the provided code.

```js
// Class color and label info.
var classInfo = [
  [  // Column 1
    {name: 'Forest', color: 'green'},  // Row 1
    {name: 'Rock', color: 'grey'},     // Row 2
  ],
  [  // Column 2
    {name: 'Water', color: 'blue'},    // Row 1
    {name: 'Grass', color: 'yellow'},  // Row 2
  ]
];

// Makes a legend entry: color and label side-by-side in a panel.
function legendEntry(info) {
  var color = ui.Panel({style: {
    width: '20px',
    height: '20px',
    backgroundColor: info.color,
    margin: '6px 0px 0px 0px'
  }});
  var label = ui.Label({
    value: info.name,
  });
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [color, label],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
    style: {
      stretch: 'horizontal',
      margin: '-6px 0px 0px 0px'
    }});
}

// Make a grid of legend entries.
var columns = [];
classInfo.forEach(function(column) {
  var rows = [];
  column.forEach(function(row) {
    rows.push(legendEntry(row));
  });
  columns.push(ui.Panel(rows));
});

// Add the legend components grid to a parent legend panel. 
var legend = ui.Panel({
  widgets: columns,
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 8px 0px 8px' 
  }
});

// Show legend on the map.
Map.add(legend);
```